# Nested Views in Django - Python

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am new to python, and making a transition from AngularJs. 
I am struggling to implement login to render specific template without refreshing the whole page.

Base.html have two templates and in turn, those two have another two.
Now all of them have different URLs, so when I hot one URL, that particular HTML is rendered, killing all the others.

My base HTML has all the elements which will always be there (like index.html)

```
<div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col s3 offset-s3">
              <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
                <div class="card-content white-text">
                  <span class="card-title">Dice</span>
                  <p>Throw dice</p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-action">
                  <a href="#dice">Let's Play</a>
                  {% comment %} <a href="#">This is a link</a> {% endcomment %}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col s3">
              <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
                <div class="card-content white-text">
                  <span class="card-title">Hangman</span>
                  <p>You know it</p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-action">
                  <a href="#hangman">Let's Play</a>
                  {% comment %} <a href="#">This is a link</a> {% endcomment %}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Picture 1 - the landing page
[image]

Picture 2
[image]

The difference between two is the URL. now when the URL is *"/#dice"* I want the top banner remains but the two boxes should disappear and other html should come up

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you read the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/language/? Sounds like this section will be particularly helpful, because you don't appear to be using inheritance at all: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/language/#id1

Comment: I have read that, but I guess it explains only what can we follow when the page is loaded for the first time.
My issue is, the page is already loaded and now I click a link which just appends another template.

Comment: That doesn't sound normal at all. Which link is it? Is it one of the ones above? (They just have `#` for the href value, all that will do is jump the window to the top of the document. Unless of course you have some javascript intervening.)

Comment: Edited. Added two images for better understanding

Comment: `/wel/` and `/wel/#dice` are considered exactly the same URL as far as Django is concerned - it will treat it as `/wel/` in both cases. The hash portion will by default move the window so the element with id `dice` is at the top of the page - you can customise/change this with Javascript if you want, but Django has noting to do with it. The "hash" portion of the URL is for client-side routing, not server-side.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a different view (in views.py) with another URL (in urls.py) and make a request with javascript to fetch HTML snippet.

Then, append that to where you need it in your page, also with Javascript.